# How to resolve "You cannot define a correlation name 'in_promozione_idx' more than once"

Tags: magento-1.7, navigation, custom-menu

I need to resolve  this error. Can you help me?

--

There has been an error processing your request
You cannot define a correlation name 'in_promozione_idx' more than once

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/ilic/active/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'in_promozione_i...', Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/ilic/active/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'in_promozione_i...', Array, NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/ilic/active/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'in_promozione_i...', Array, NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(104): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'in_promozione_i...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/community/Simtech/Searchanise/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(33): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->getCount(Object(Ilic_LayeredNavigation_Model_Catalog_Filter_Attribute))
#5 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/local/Ilic/LayeredNavigation/Model/Catalog/Filter/Attribute.php(33): Simtech_Searchanise_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->getCount(Object(Ilic_LayeredNavigation_Model_Catalog_Filter_Attribute))
#6 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Ilic_LayeredNavigation_Model_Catalog_Filter_Attribute->_getItemsData()
#7 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#8 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#9 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#10 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/design/frontend/default/ilic/template/ilic_layerednavigation/view.phtml(52): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#11 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/i...')
#12 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#13 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/local/Ilic/LayeredNavigation/Block/Catalog/Layer.php(95): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Ilic_LayeredNavigation_Block_Catalog_Layer->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#20 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/local/EM/Themeframework/Helper/Theme.php(82): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#21 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/design/frontend/default/ilic/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(43): EM_Themeframework_Helper_Theme->display(Object(Mage_Page_Block_Html), '2columns-left')
#22 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/i...')
#23 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#24 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/community/Simtech/Searchanise/controllers/CategoryController.php(68): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#30 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Simtech_Searchanise_CategoryController->viewAction()
#31 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#32 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#33 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 /var/www/html/ilic/active/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 /var/www/html/ilic/active/index.php(143): Mage::run('', 'store')
#36 {main}

--
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar things are solved/discussed here: [You cannot define a correlation name '*_idx' more than once](https://support.amasty.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/12/5/you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-_idx-more-than-once), and here: [Magento Layered Navigation “You cannot define a correlation name 'mycustomattribute' more than once ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524017/magento-layered-navigation-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-mycustomattrib).

Main idea is that there are more than one navigation blocks defined in page layout. All duplicates have to be removed to make everything work properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It means two blocks are calling there so check and remove "catalog/layer_view" type block from here -
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml
or
app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/layout/catalog.xml

and remove block with navigation: