# Call layer filter in Custom Design in Category

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layered-navigation, filter

I need some custom list file so i used in this way. Here how to call filter. This is **1column.phtml**

[image]

Comment: what to trying to do here you want to display `filter on 1column layout`

Comment: Here i want to display filter also

Answer (score 1):

call the layer in `content` reference

```
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

Comment: I already tried but it's not show anything is there anything i need to be done in phtml file

Comment: `echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();` try this one.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean

Comment: `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>` try that

Comment: this is working <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view')->setTemplate('em_layerednavigation/view.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: but if i click any link it shows error You cannot define a correlation name 'mobile_design_idx' more than once

Comment: remove code from other places...

Comment: Where i removed from category then ???

Comment: if you added this in category design in admin panel

Comment: i already removed from category custom design

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58477/how-to-resolve-you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-in-promozione-idx-more-th